# Why does the nested class in a ConfigurationProperties class need to be static?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using an `application.yml` file as the external configuration in my spring boot application which is bound to `AppConfig.java` using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. Inside `AppConfig.java` I have nested classes based on the hierarchy in `application.yml`. When I use `static` to declare the nested classes, everything works fine. But recently in a project I missed `static` for one of the nested classes and it led to a `NullPointerException`. Through online resources, I have read when to and when not make nested classes static. However, I need to understand how the binding of `application.yml` and `AppConfig.java` occurs in spring boot and why the nested classes need to be `static`.

#### application.yml

```
spring:
  foo:
    host: localhost
  bar:
    endpoint: localhost
```

#### AppConfig.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("spring")
public class AppConfig {
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;
    public static class Foo {
        private String host;
        // getter, setter
    }
    public class Bar {
        private String host;
        // getter, setter
    }
    //getters, setters
}
```

When I Autowire `AppConfig.java` in other classes, `appConfig.getFoo()` works fine but `appConfig.getBar()` leads to a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: just a guess, but maybe spring is having difficulties in creating non-static inner class instances, because you must provide a reference to the enclosing instance when instantiating non-static inner classes. Making it static should not be a big problem though. Or you can let it non static and make it a non-public class in the same .java

Comment: If you look into stack trace of `NPE` you can easily find the reason why it was thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found why it must be static particularly.
However, I have found other comment in the documentation. It is related to the validation of @ConfigurationProperties bean.
Here it is:

> The configuration properties validator is created very early in the application’s lifecycle, and declaring the @Bean method as static lets the bean be created without having to instantiate the @Configuration class.

It was about inner class.
More details : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, this is inline with why one would use a static nested class in the first place. However, the documentation also says `Doing so avoids any problems that may be caused by early instantiation`. Any idea what these problems could be?

Answer (score 1):

Spring is using a Binder to apply the properties to ConfigurationProperty beans.

The Binder, that Spring uses, can create instances, if a getX() doesn't return a class. This however is limited to simple constructors. A class, which is not static, can only be instantiated with a reference to the instance, in which it is contained.

If this is REALLY, what you need, you could create an instance of the class during bean creation.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("spring")
public class AppConfig {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
    private Bar bar = new Bar();
    public static class Foo {
        private String host;
        // getter, setter
    }
    public class Bar {
        private String host;
        // getter, setter
    }
    //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now! The nested classes can be instantiated without instantiating the `@ConfigurationProperties` class. What I do not understand now is, the spring document given in the answer above mentions `Doing so avoids any problems that may be caused by early instantiation` . I am unable to think of the problems which can arise!

Answer (score 0):

The inner class has to be static as spring while instantiating the main class, won't be able to set the properties for the inner class because there is no instance yet. So the inner static class is frist of all instantiated by the classloader then, spring will be able to set its properties.